# Calling a Magento attribute

Tags: attributes, template

Hi guys so I've opened my **list.phtml** file and located the code that displays the **name** attribute for the products displayed in my catalog.

Could someone possible show me how they would add an extra attribute to this?

I have an attribute named Manufacturer, I'm just wondering how I can call this attribute so I don't just have the name of the product I have the manufacturer.

Any help would be great, here's an example of my code:

```
<div class="details-area">
                        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                        <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <div class="rating-box">
                                    <div class="rating" style="width:0"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php
                            if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                                $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                                foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                                    $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);   $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                                    echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that the manufacturer attribute is set to "Used in Product Listing". Then, you can simply use something like this (I just added the third row):

```
<div class="details-area">
    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
    <div class="manufacturer"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')); ?></div>
    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="ratings">
            <div class="rating-box">
                <div class="rating" style="width:0"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
        if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
            $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
            foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);   $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
            }
        }
    ?>
```